# JQuery Validation validate() function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#saveButton').click(function(){
        $("#mainForm").validate();
        $('#mainForm').submit();
    });
}
```

And this form

```
<form method="post" action="" name="mainForm" id="mainForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

When I click my save button, it says that validate() function could not be found.

Why is this happening? My JQuery is included before jQuery Validation.

Also if I change the line

```
$("#mainForm").validate();
```

to

```
$.validate();
```

the validation works.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Post your html please.

Comment: I changed my post and added the HTML.

Comment: There must be something else in your code that causes this problem, because the validate function is found when I execute this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8jYtP/

Comment: So much code is missing.  Post a **complete** concise example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#saveButton').click(function(){
        $("#mainForm").validate();
        $('#mainForm').submit();
    });
} // < - missing );
```

`.validate()` is the initialization method and you're not initializing it until AFTER the button is first clicked.  (You also failed to close your DOM ready handler properly)

This is all that's required...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mainForm").validate({ ... rules, options, etc. ... });
});
```

The form is initialized, data is validated, the click is captured, and the "valid" form is submitted... all automatically by the plugin.

**Basic Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/DMSKh/**

Comment: @tzortzik, You have failed to properly include the plugin or the path in the file includes is broken.  Otherwise, fix your question to show a complete example demonstrating the issue.